# Cron Task scheduled to run only once, but is running every 30 mins

Tags: spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have cron job scheduled in spring boot to run 11:30PM daily, it ran fine for few days and recently it is triggering each hour at least thrice and runs for 0 seconds. The task is to move data from some DB to MongoDB

The cron time defined is `@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 23 * * *")`